# jquery form inserting with php

Tags: php, jquery-mobile, mysqli, insert

please help find the sourse of my codes issue...when I click request the page just refreshes with all the data gone but nothing is inserted into the db...
here is the image of the db and the code! what do I need to change to be able to insert the data along with the username of the logged in user?
![the database]https://i.stack.imgur.com/iz8Cn.jpg

@user1151316 I made the changes and here is the code removing the pointless comments...the data is not being inserted and after submitting I get a blank screen...

```
        <?php
        //require_once 'includes/dbconnect.php';
        session_start();

         if (isset($_POST["request"])) 
         {
            //print_r($_POST);die;
        //take care of injections
        $service = mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$_POST['service']);
        $service_details  = mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$_POST['service_details']);
        $duedate  = mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$_POST['duedate']);
        $postdate  = mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$_POST['postdate']); //READ ONLY DATE POST



        // Insert data into mysql + LOGGED IN USERS USERNAME TO BE INSERTED
         $sql = "INSERT INTO serviceposts VALUES ('".$_SESSION["username"]."','".$service."', '".$service_details."', '".$duedate."', '".$postdate."')";

        $result= $link -> query($sql) or die (mysqli_error($link));

         echo "($result)";
        // if successfully insert data into database, displays message "Successful".
        if($result){
                echo "request post success!";
                 echo'<script>window.location="http://localhost/Project2/User.php#viewrequests";</script>';     
        }
        else {
            echo "Possible data input error";       

                }
        $link->close();
        }

        ?>
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
        <head>
        <script src="includes/js/modernizr.js"></script>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link href="jqueryAssets/jquery.mobile.icons.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <link href="jqueryAssets/Mobi~Style~Me.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <link href="jqueryAssets/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <link href="jqueryAssets/jquery.ui.theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <link href="jqueryAssets/jquery.mobile.icons-1.4.5.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <link href="jqueryAssets/jquery.mobile.structure-1.4.5.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <link href="jqueryAssets/jquery.ui.datepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <style type="text/css">
        body,td,th {
            font-family: Constantia, "Lucida Bright", "DejaVu Serif", Georgia, serif;
            color: #303;
        }
        body {
            background-image: url();
        }
        </style>
        <link href="jqueryAssets/jquery.ui.core.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <style type="text/css">
        a {
            font-weight: bolder;
        }
        </style>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="jqueryAssets/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
        <script src="jqueryAssets/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="jqueryAssets/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
        <script src="jqueryAssets/jquery-ui-1.9.2.dialog.custom.min.js"></script>
        <script src="jqueryAssets/jquery-1.8.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="jqueryAssets/jquery-ui-1.9.2.datepicker.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <title>MyITjobs</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        </head>  
        <body>  
          <div data-role="page" id="servicerequest" data-theme="c">
        <div data-role="header" data-add-back-btn="true"><h4>IT~Service Request</h4></div>
        <span align="center"><?php if (isset($_SESSION["username"]))
        {
         echo "".$_SESSION["username"]."";
        }
        ?>
        </span>
        <div data-role="content" class="ui-field-contain" align="center" data-content-theme="c">
             <form style="align-items:justify" method="post" action="" id="servicerequest">
             <input type="hidden" name="service" id="selected_service"/>
            <span>
            <select name="selectmenu" required class="ui-bar-c slidedown" id="service" data-collapsed="false" onchange="onchangeservice()">
            <option selected="selected" class="ui-selectmenu-placeholder">IT-Services</option>
            <option value="service1" id="MobileApps">Mobile Apps Development</option>
            <option value="service2" id="WebDev">Website Development</option>
            <option value="service3" id="Programming">Programming</option>
                   </select>
                   </span>
                   <br>
            <span>
            <div data-role="fieldcontain">
            <label for="service_details">IT~Service Request Details</label>
              <textarea name="service_details" cols="35" rows="6" id="service_details" placeholder="Input Request details"></textarea>
            </div>
            </span>
              <span>        
                <label for="duedate">Set Due Date:</label>
                <input type="datetime-local" required name="duedate" id="duedate" data-mini="true">
                </span> 
                 <br>   
              <span>
               <label for="datetime-local">Request Date</label>
               <DateTime id="postdate" data-mini="true">
                <?php      
              $postdate = date("Y-m-d, H:i");
                echo "$postdate";
                   ?>

               </span>  
               <input type="hidden" name="postdate" value="<?php echo $postdate; ?>"/>
               <br>
           <fieldset class="ui-grid-a">
        <div class="ui-block-a">
               <button type="submit" data-icon="check" data-iconshadow="true" data-iconpos="left" id="request" name="request">Request</button></div>
        <div class="ui-block-b">
          <button type="reset" data-icon="delete" data-iconshadow="true" data-iconpos="left">Cancel</button>
          </div>
         </fieldset>  
         <script>

             function onchangeservice()
             {
                 var service_option = $( "#service option:selected" ).text();  
                 $('#selected_service').val(service_option);
             }
                </script>
                </form>
                 </div>     
        <div data-role="footer" data-theme="c" align="center">
                  </div>
             </div> 
        </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: Have you watched the request / response in the browser's console? Have you checked the error logs?

Comment: you call session_start() **AFTER** you've already been using session variables, and you have NO form field named `request`, so `$_POST['request']` never gets set, skipping all of your db code.

Comment: Although this does not seem to have anything to do with jQuery, why are you including so many different versions of it (and jQuery UI)?

Comment: hey blanchard...I am a beginner with php and jquery, I am using xampp and the error logs are not really easily accessible especially for someone like me...plus I have a migrane and I just want the data to insert...i tried echoing the errors, if any, before the echo "($result)"; line but I get nothing...

Comment: Marc B...thanks for the  pointers...the 'request ' is referring to the submit button...

Comment: jeroen...my mobile site is a jquery mobile site...so I just copied the head tag code from the other page...

Comment: The error logs are *totally* accessible on XAMPP `\xampp\apache\logs`

Comment: thanks Jay...the last error logged was around 3 hours ago...but I have been working on plenty of code ever since...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do below steps to resolve the issue :

- Add a new hidden field 
  `<input type="hidden" name="service" id="selected_service"/>`
- Add onchange function to select box as

  `<select name="selectmenu" required class="ui-bar-c slidedown" id="service" data-collapsed="false" onchange="onchangeservice()">`
- Replace your script into function

  `function onchangeservice()
   {
          var service_option = $( "#service option:selected" ).text();
          $('#selected_service').val(service_option);
    }`

Full code will look like :

```
   `<?php
    require_once 'includes/dbconnect.php';
    session_start();
    //require_once 'includes/dbconnect.php';

    /* if (isset($_SESSION["username"]) && !empty($_SESSION["username"])){
    echo "".strtoupper($_SESSION['username'])."(Sign out)"; }else{
    echo "Sign In";
    } */

     if (isset($_POST["request"])) 
     {
        //print_r($_POST);die;
    //take care of injections
    $service = mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$_POST['service']);
    $service_details  = mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$_POST['service_details']);
    $duedate  = mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$_POST['duedate']);
    $postdate  = mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$_POST['postdate']); //READ ONLY DATE POST



    // Insert data into mysql + LOGGED IN USERS USERNAME TO BE INSERTED
     $sql = "INSERT INTO serviceposts VALUES ('".$_SESSION["username"]."','".$service."', '".$service_details."', '".$duedate."', '".$postdate."')";

    $result= $link -> query($sql) or die (mysqli_error($link));

     echo "($result)";
    // if successfully insert data into database, displays message "Successful".
    if($result){
            echo "request post success!";
             echo'<script>window.location="http://localhost/Project2/User.php#viewrequests";</script>'; 

       // header('Location: ../User.php?success=1');

    }
    else {
        echo "Possible data input error";
    //header('Location: ../user.php?error=1');


            }
    $link->close();
    }

    ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <script src="includes/js/modernizr.js"></script>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="jqueryAssets/jquery.mobile.icons.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="jqueryAssets/Mobi~Style~Me.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="jqueryAssets/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="jqueryAssets/jquery.ui.theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="jqueryAssets/jquery.mobile.icons-1.4.5.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="jqueryAssets/jquery.mobile.structure-1.4.5.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="jqueryAssets/jquery.ui.datepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <style type="text/css">
    body,td,th {
        font-family: Constantia, "Lucida Bright", "DejaVu Serif", Georgia, serif;
        color: #303;
    }
    body {
        background-image: url();
    }
    </style>
    <link href="jqueryAssets/jquery.ui.core.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <style type="text/css">
    a {
        font-weight: bolder;
    }
    </style>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jqueryAssets/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jqueryAssets/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jqueryAssets/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jqueryAssets/jquery-ui-1.9.2.dialog.custom.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jqueryAssets/jquery-1.8.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="jqueryAssets/jquery-ui-1.9.2.datepicker.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <title>MyITjobs</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>  
    <body>  
      <div data-role="page" id="servicerequest" data-theme="c">
    <div data-role="header" data-add-back-btn="true"><h4>IT~Service Request</h4></div>
    <span align="center"><?php if (isset($_SESSION["username"]))
    {
     echo "".$_SESSION["username"]."";
    }
    ?>
    </span>
    <div data-role="content" class="ui-field-contain" align="center" data-content-theme="c">
         <form style="align-items:justify" method="post" action="" id="servicerequest">
         <input type="hidden" name="service" id="selected_service"/>
        <span>
        <select name="selectmenu" required class="ui-bar-c slidedown" id="service" data-collapsed="false" onchange="onchangeservice()">
        <option selected="selected" class="ui-selectmenu-placeholder">IT-Services</option>
        <option value="service1" id="MobileApps">Mobile Apps Development</option>
        <option value="service2" id="WebDev">Website Development</option>
        <option value="service3" id="Programming">Programming</option>
               </select>
               </span>
               <br>
        <span>
        <div data-role="fieldcontain">
        <label for="service_details">IT~Service Request Details</label>
          <textarea name="service_details" cols="35" rows="6" id="service_details" placeholder="Input Request details"></textarea>
        </div>
        </span>
          <span>        
            <label for="duedate">Set Due Date:</label>
            <input type="datetime-local" required name="duedate" id="duedate" data-mini="true">
            </span> 
             <br>   
          <span>
           <label for="datetime-local">Request Date</label>
           <DateTime id="postdate" data-mini="true">
            <?php      
          $postdate = date("Y-m-d, H:i");
            echo "$postdate";
               ?>

           </span>  
           <input type="hidden" name="postdate" value="<?php echo $postdate; ?>"/>
           <br>
       <fieldset class="ui-grid-a">
    <div class="ui-block-a">
           <button type="submit" data-icon="check" data-iconshadow="true" data-iconpos="left" id="request" name="request">Request</button></div>
    <div class="ui-block-b">
      <button type="reset" data-icon="delete" data-iconshadow="true" data-iconpos="left">Cancel</button>
      </div>
     </fieldset>  
     <script>

         function onchangeservice()
         {
             var service_option = $( "#service option:selected" ).text();  
             $('#selected_service').val(service_option);
         }


            </script>
            </form>



                 </div>     
    <div data-role="footer" data-theme="c" align="center">
              </div>
         </div> 
    </body>
    </html>`
```

Comment: the database connection is the includes/dbconnect.php how else will it connect?

Comment: yesss! it has inserted all the fields!!! thank you! apart from the username...that is not being inserted I think because the session is not being read...             and the page just refreshes after I submit...nothing happens but when I check in the database the service, service_details, duedate and postdate are inserted!                                                    btw I removed the comment lines on the first require_once line for it to post...

Answer (score 0):

You have to do lots of fixes.

- You have not added any name attribute to all the input types so they were not posting.
- You should write code much indented and clean so that you can find out the issues.
- Don't include files multiple times.
- Remove unwanted commented code.

Please try below code :

```
<?php
    require_once 'includes/dbconnect.php';

    session_start();
    //require_once 'includes/dbconnect.php';

    /* if (isset($_SESSION["username"]) && !empty($_SESSION["username"])){
    echo "".strtoupper($_SESSION['username'])."(Sign out)"; }else{
    echo "Sign In";
    } */

     if (isset($_POST["request"])) 
     {
    //take care of injections
    $service = mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$_POST['service']);
    $service_details  = mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$_POST['service_details']);
    $duedate  = mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$_POST['duedate']);
    $postdate  = mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$_POST['postdate']); //READ ONLY DATE POST



    // Insert data into mysql + LOGGED IN USERS USERNAME TO BE INSERTED
     $sql = "INSERT INTO serviceposts VALUES ('".$_SESSION["username"]."','".$service."', '".$service_details."', '".$duedate."', '".$postdate."')";

    $result= $link -> query($sql) or die (mysqli_error($link));

     echo "($result)";
    // if successfully insert data into database, displays message "Successful".
    if($result){
            echo "request post success!";
             echo'<script>window.location="http://localhost/Project2/User.php#viewrequests";</script>'; 

       // header('Location: ../User.php?success=1');

    }
    else {
        echo "Possible data input error";
    //header('Location: ../user.php?error=1');


            }
    $link->close();
    }

    ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <script src="includes/js/modernizr.js"></script>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="jqueryAssets/jquery.mobile.icons.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="jqueryAssets/Mobi~Style~Me.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="jqueryAssets/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="jqueryAssets/jquery.ui.theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="jqueryAssets/jquery.mobile.icons-1.4.5.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="jqueryAssets/jquery.mobile.structure-1.4.5.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="jqueryAssets/jquery.ui.datepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <style type="text/css">
    body,td,th {
        font-family: Constantia, "Lucida Bright", "DejaVu Serif", Georgia, serif;
        color: #303;
    }
    body {
        background-image: url();
    }
    </style>
    <link href="jqueryAssets/jquery.ui.core.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <style type="text/css">
    a {
        font-weight: bolder;
    }
    </style>
    <script src="jqueryAssets/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jqueryAssets/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jqueryAssets/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jqueryAssets/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jqueryAssets/jquery-ui-1.9.2.dialog.custom.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jqueryAssets/jquery-1.8.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="jqueryAssets/jquery-ui-1.9.2.datepicker.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <title>MyITjobs</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>  
    <body>  
      <div data-role="page" id="servicerequest" data-theme="c">
    <div data-role="header" data-add-back-btn="true"><h4>IT~Service Request</h4></div>
    <span align="center"><?php if (isset($_SESSION["username"]))
    {
     echo "".$_SESSION["username"]."";
    }
    ?>
    </span>
    <div data-role="content" class="ui-field-contain" align="center" data-content-theme="c">
         <form style="align-items:justify" method="post" action="" id="servicerequest">
        <span>
        <select name="selectmenu" required class="ui-bar-c slidedown" id="service" data-collapsed="false">
        <option selected="selected" class="ui-selectmenu-placeholder">IT-Services</option>
        <option value="service1" id="MobileApps">Mobile Apps Development</option>
        <option value="service2" id="WebDev">Website Development</option>
        <option value="service3" id="Programming">Programming</option>
               </select>
               </span>
               <br>
        <span>
        <div data-role="fieldcontain">
        <label for="service_details">IT~Service Request Details</label>
          <textarea name="service_details" cols="35" rows="6" id="service_details" placeholder="Input Request details"></textarea>
        </div>
        </span>
          <span>        
            <label for="duedate">Set Due Date:</label>
            <input type="datetime-local" required name="duedate" id="duedate" data-mini="true">
            </span> 
             <br>   
          <span>
           <label for="datetime-local">Request Date</label>
           <DateTime id="postdate" data-mini="true">
            <?php      
          $postdate = date("Y-m-d, H:i");
            echo "$postdate";
               ?>

           </span>  
           <input type="hidden" name="postdate" value="<?php echo $postdate; ?>"/>
           <br>
       <fieldset class="ui-grid-a">
    <div class="ui-block-a">
           <button type="submit" data-icon="check" data-iconshadow="true" data-iconpos="left" id="request" name="request">Request</button></div>
    <div class="ui-block-b">
      <button type="reset" data-icon="delete" data-iconshadow="true" data-iconpos="left">Cancel</button>
      </div>
     </fieldset>  
     <script>
     $( "#service option:selected" ).text();  
            </script>
            </form>               
                     </div>     
    <div data-role="footer" data-theme="c" align="center">
              </div>
         </div> 
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Why should the OP "try this"? Please add an explanation of what you did and why you did it that way, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Comment: @Jay : I also added my comment above the code. Please check.

Comment: thanks user1151316 the data inserted was the service details and both the due and post dates...but the service I selected was not inserted?!  and after I clicked request the page just refreshed...I thought it would atleast tell me  success...

Comment: the service is not being inserted...its a set and in the jquery a select option  but the js code I put at the bottom is not making a difference!                  oh and how can the username be inserted when the user in session is not being recognized? thats why starting the session again was proving to be conflicting!

Comment: btw this page is a protected page...only a logged in user accesses it...remember the login.php you helped me with, after logging in they go to their profile page and can post a request...so the session would have to spill over to this page if thats possible...and I really appreciate you taking your time to help, you are truly a God send @user1151316!!

Comment: hey user1151316...have you gone away?